# SNR of an image in C++ using OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

How can I get the SNR of an image in C++ using OpenCV?

I have the original image and the other with Gaussian noise.

Comment: No distractions, no chit-chat (read [help→tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)) that directly applies to your "Thanks for attention" 
It is not considered impolite to leave that out, but it is wasting readers time when you put it in and that **is** impolite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting from [the OpenCV example here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/highgui/video-input-psnr-ssim/video-input-psnr-ssim.html#image-similarity-psnr-and-ssim), which explains how to derive the PSNR (peak signal to noise ratio) from the MSE (mean squared error), you can use the following function:

```
double getPSNR(const Mat& I1, const Mat& I2)
{
    Mat s1;
    absdiff(I1, I2, s1);       // |I1 - I2|
    s1.convertTo(s1, CV_32F);  // cannot make a square on 8 bits
    s1 = s1.mul(s1);           // |I1 - I2|^2

    Scalar s = sum(s1);         // sum elements per channel

    double sse = s.val[0] + s.val[1] + s.val[2]; // sum channels

    if( sse <= 1e-10) // for small values return zero
        return 0;
    else
    {
        double  mse =sse /(double)(I1.channels() * I1.total());
        double psnr = 10.0*log10((255*255)/mse);
        return psnr;
    }
}
```

Again, quoting from the linked page (for posterity), the explanations is as follows:

[image: PSNR]

Comment: I had seen this function there, I just wanted an alternative to calculate the SNR, so I will use this same function.